# How to include one component and exclude another one by link in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

For example:

If in file component1.vue is included component2:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <app-component2 />
  </div>
</template>
```

In component2.vue is included component3:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <app-component3 />
  </div>
</template>
```

And in component3 is link:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nuxt-link to="">Abc</nuxt-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

How to include component4 instead of component2 in component1 after click on link Abc?